# Passing Values from Page to Another page in List

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

this is mine model

```
 public class QMSRejection
        {
    
            public string Date { get; set; }
    
            public string Grade { get; set; }
    
            
            public string Resd { get; set; }
    
            public string Remarks { get; set; }
        }
```

this is mine firstpage.xaml.cs from where I am passing a data to another page !

```
     List<QMSRejection> DataToSave = new List<QMSRejection>();
                var rej = new QMSRejection();

                rej.Date = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
                rej.Grade = GradeID;
                rej.Resd = ResdId;
                
                DataToSave.Add(rej);
 await Navigation.PushAsync(new Rejection2ndForm(DataToSave));
```

now on the second page I am receiving it, data is coming everything working fine !

```
 public partial class Page2 : ContentPage
  {
    List<QMSRejection> DataToSave = new List<QMSRejection>();
    public Rejection2ndForm(List<QMSRejection> models)
    {
      InitializeComponent ();
      DataToSave = models;

    }
  }

            var rej = new QMSRejection();
            rej.Remarks = ent3.Text.ToString();
            DataToSave.add(rej);
```

I have a fields Remarks which I am trying to add to existing data coming from page 1.But these lines are creating another IEnumerable in the datatoSave List and remarks field not getting added to previous data ! What should I do in place of these lines to do ?
As I have to add remarks field through page2.xaml.cs !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this creates a **new** `QMSRejection` object and adds it to your list

```
var rej = new QMSRejection();
rej.Remarks = ent3.Text.ToString();
DataToSave.add(rej);
```

if you instead want to modify an **existing** `QMSRejection` object

```
// [0] means the first object in the list
DataToSave[0].Remarks = ent3.Text.ToString();
```